# How to force standard output as FortranForm while calling a script from terminal

Tags: output-formatting, scripting

Here's a simple script saved in the file fortranOutput.wls

```
x = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]]
d=FortranForm[x]
Print[d]
```

When I call this function from the terminal :

```
./fortranOuput.wls 1.2*^-8
```

I get the output (I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS):

```
FortranForm[1.2*^-8]
```

Obviously, the answer I expect (and receive in the Mathematica environment) is:

```
1.2e-8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]]
Print[x]
Echo[ToString@FortranForm[x]]
```

I am on Windows 7-x64 with v12.2.0:

```
> C:\MathematicaWork>ascript.wls "1.2*^-8"
> 1.2*^-8
> >> 1.2e-8
```

Comment: my machine is Ubuntu 20.04. It works but I am getting the extra characters ">>"

Comment: Try `Print` instead of `Echo` ?

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks.